# How to create a helpful tooltip in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, tooltip

I would like to create a tooltip like thing in Android to help show my users what something is, as people have told me they don't know what it is. For an idea of what i'm after here is a drawing:

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone just joining us from searching this.

This is a better Holo solution https://gist.github.com/romannurik/3982005

Comment: IMO That's not a better solution as it requires User to long-press on the UI element to see it (which would conflict with copy/paste OS feature in an EditText), the Toast is also not very explicit in telling the User what UI element it is attached/referring to.

Answer (score 22):

This is the `QuickAction` UI pattern. Take a look at:

1. [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid), a collection of Android widgets - namely the `QuickAction...` widgets such as `QuickActionBar`, `QuickActionGrid` etc
2. [How to create a QuickAction dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: I already use GreenDroid, even forked it. The Gallery3D actions look like what I want, I'll have a deeper look into them

Comment: Thanks very much, I used the drawables from the "How to" guide and created a new translucent activitiy and positioned everything using dpi. Thanks :)

Comment: GreenDroid now seems deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

another alternative would be "super-tooltips":

https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips

here's a demo of it:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.supertooltips

Comment: This has an issue with right or left tooltips being clipped.

Answer (score 4):

There are several libraries available that will assist you in implementing tooltips in Android.

I recommend the Android Tooltip library which you can find on [Github](https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip)

Example usage:

```
Tooltip.make(this,
    new Builder(101)
    .anchor(aView, Gravity.BOTTOM)
    .closePolicy(new ClosePolicy()
        .insidePolicy(true, false)
        .outsidePolicy(true, false), 3000)
    .activateDelay(800)
    .showDelay(300)
    .text(R.string.hello_world)
    .maxWidth(500)
    .withArrow(true)
    .withOverlay(true)
    floatingAnimation(AnimationBuilder.DEFAULT)
    .build()
).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use android-formidable-validation's .betterSetError() feature, customising the ErrorPopup balloon's background drawable and the error exclamation mark icon that gets set as the drawableRight in the EditText. To fine tune to your requirements you'd need to play with the code that lays out the ErrorPopup.