# Add Description or Hint to Button in android

Tags: android

[image]

How do add description or hint. When i touch a Button / ImageButton, I need description or hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check => [How to create a helpful tooltip in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542694/how-to-create-a-helpful-tooltip-in-android),

Comment: Google the Popup-window you will get hint

Comment: Nice Idea.. But android doesn't provide such things. like Cursor Over of windows. Better to make a Custom View which displayed when some Buttons/ImageButtons are selected..

Comment: You can try and detect a Long Press?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this approach is a good idea since when you touch a `Button` in `Android`, it get's in pressed state, and when you release it will trigger the button's action. I suggest you use a different approach such as a properly formated `TextView` under the `Button` or `ImageButton`.