# How to give information to a user by information window

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show an information window beside a button to inform user what this button is or the next step in a process of using the app.Attached photo clarify what I mean.I would be so grateful if someone could help.
[image]

Comment: looking for https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView?

Comment: This question also referring the similar information tooltip [Helpful tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542694/how-to-create-a-helpful-tooltip-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

First use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), show the message in a textview with the background you want, and finally adjust it with the align options that gives you the RelativeLayout. I think is a good approach.